# openerp css classes definition, what is the meaning of .openerp .oe_form .oe_styling_v8 b for example

Tags: css, openerp-7, openerp-8, odoo-8, openerp-web-module

I am new to openerp, i can see some css class definitions like the following:

***.openerp .oe_form .oe_styling_v8 b***

Can you please explain to me what does it mean?
I can see to much css classes starting with .openerp .oe
how we define two css classes on the same line, this is not allowed in css

Thanks in advance

Comment: They're not defining multiple styles, they use what's called a descendant selector.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i got the idea. I searched for css descendent selectors and now its clear. The problem for me was with css not openerp